# A connection to the Jupyter server could not be established. JupyterLab will continue trying to reconnect on Sagemaker

Tags: python, connection, amazon-sagemaker

I am using python3 on SageMaker AWS and this issue is happening:

A connection to the Jupyter server could not be established. JupyterLab will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or Jupyter server configuration.

Dismiss

This happens generally when I make some pause on my scripts. Others, it's suddenly. Sometimes the kernel is dropped and I have to rerun everything! I am using a corporative account and this problems is reported just by me. Do I have to update something?

Comment: Generally happens due to network connection issues (if you're using VPN or such). Also, are you on Jupyter Lab v3? V3 has a better retry logic.

Comment: I am still facing this problem. Sometimes, the warning message appears, but the kernel still online. Other, it is dropped. Even now, in the updated SageMaker jupyter notebook it is happening..